I'm using create react app and I'm not able to install the eslint
I'm using create react app and trying to install eslint, but it's not working. Eslint is not generating a json file. The option to create a json file doesn't even appear when I code npx eslint --init. When the eslint installation ends, it create a js file ou mjs file. I guess all the plugins are installed correctly. I don't know if the create react app is not able to deal with the current version of eslint.
I've tried
npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest eslint-plugin-react@latest @typescript-eslint/parser@latest eslint@latest --save-dev --force

OT: CRA has been deprecated since early 2023. I can recommend vite as the most similar option. As easy or easier to set up.

Firstly, Check the dubble time the ESLint is available or not in dependancy,
then check by run
"npm ls eslint" if it is ok but not working,
then clean the npm cache by run this
"npm cache clean --force" after this done.
Reinstall the "npm install"
and after this done you do it by
"npx eslint --init"
this will not work as properly then check documentation fully by your expactation veiw and than you would do it perfactly.
